# Metro JS can't get Tiles to be clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using MetroJS to make metro tiles for my website, however I'm getting annoyed off about the lack of documentation on the site. Could anyone help me please get this tile clickable? It's just not working whichever way i try it. It worked with an anchor as the link, but that means i can't use the bounce function. Here is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cdn/metrojs/MetroJs.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cdn/metrojs/MetroJs.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="live-tile" class="live-tile" data-mode="none" data-bounce="true" data-link="http://google.com/">
        <img src="/cdn/metro-icons/Web%20Browsers/Internet%20Explorer.png" class="live-tile full">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(".live-tile").liveTile({
        click: function ($tile, tileData) {
            var id = $tile.attr("id");
            window.location = "postpage.php?name=" + id;
            return false; // or return true; 
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Could someone help me please, this was meant to be easy, why can't i just use a standard anchor and not this jQuery nonsense?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a standard anchor tag inside a live tile with no issues. If you add the full class to it, it will take up the tile by default. If you nest it in a div it will take on the accent color of its parent. data-link is only a helper and it is much less preferable to an anchor

```
<div id="live-tile" class="live-tile" data-mode="none" data-bounce="true">
<a href="http://google.com/" class="full">
    <img src="/cdn/metro-icons/Web%20Browsers/Internet%20Explorer.png" class="full">
</a>
</div>
```

You can also bind a click this way

```
$(".live-tile").liveTile().on("click", function(e){ /* do stuff */ });
```